# PHP Police API not returning a result

Tags: php, api

This is my first time using accessing an API via PHP. I am trying to use data from police.uk.

Here is my PHP code:

```
    $lat = '52.629729';
    $long = '-1.131592';
    $date = '2013-01';

    $get = file_get_contents("http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=".$lat."&lng=".$long."&date=".$date);
    $json = json_decode($get, true);
    echo $json['location'];
```

API documentation: http://data.police.uk/docs/method/crime-street/

I am not getting any response with this call (nothing is being displayed on the page).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you got error reporting enabled?

Comment: That call returns an enumerated array, with `location` as a __subarray__ key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to the API returns something like this:

```
array (size=1105)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'category' => string 'anti-social-behaviour' (length=21)
      'location_type' => string 'Force' (length=5)
      'location' => 
        array (size=3)
          'latitude' => string '52.626948' (length=9)
          'street' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'longitude' => string '-1.112172' (length=9)
      'context' => string '' (length=0)
      'outcome_status' => null
      'persistent_id' => string '' (length=0)
```

In other words, there are multiple entries. Furthermore, the location info is yet another array:

```
array (size=3)
  'latitude' => string '52.626948' (length=9)
  'street' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 882380
      'name' => string 'On or near Cedar Road' (length=21)
  'longitude' => string '-1.112172' (length=9)
```

To output all locations (e.g. all street names), you could do something like the following:

```
foreach($json as $entry) {
    echo $entry['location']['street']['name'].'<br />';
}
```

Or just output the location of the first entry if you desire:

```
$json[0]['location']['street']['name'];
```

Tip: Use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) on a variable to see how it is laid out.

Tip 2: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file to output all errors when you're developing.

Comment: location is also an array, your code will result in an `array to string conversion` error

Comment: @user574632 How embarrassing of me to miss that; thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

The api returns an array of objects. By setting true in json_decode you create a multidimentional php array.

You must include the numerical key of the item you want to access, plus the keys of the nested arrays, eg:

```
echo $json[0]['location']['street']['name'];//outputs: On or near Cedar Road
```